# Access Site file using IP address.

Tags: apache, web, ftp, centos, webserver

I have a [site](https://www.az-lily.com) .

This site was previously owned by another customer.
So after contract and negtiation and all, we changed the Domain and Server( Created new website) 
Since current Url will point to newer site we created. 
Is it possible to view the older site?
I have its IP address(old one) , Its credential , logins, apache , putty logins detals everything. 
 
Since we need to have access to Database, MYSQL, We cant now login past admin screen. `www.az-lily.com/admin` because, we have already changed, DNS , name server and point it to New server. 

As mentioned before, I have an access to its core files via putty. 
Is it possible to view the website from IP address of the website? 
If not , then How can I visit the site? 
Just for information,The old server is still there, As I have an access to its FTP and all files are still there.
I have tried to access the page via ftp url `[IPadress]/home/sv01/www/html`removing home and sv01 from here. But it gives me permission Denied.

Comment: If the site itself is up and running, and only the dns record is pointing to an other ip, you can easily do this _locally_ by adding an entry in `hosts` file.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Yes the site is still there. I made a new site from new server and changed the dns of the domain, so I cant locate the site with url now. Only I have is IP address which gives me Permission denied. How can I add entry in Hosts? If there is any link for references or if u may help .

Comment: @ZorgoZ omg. u SAVED MY LIFE. Life Saver... Thank u .. added Ip and site name on Host with admin permission. And old site opened flawlessly.. Everything.. Thank u so much.. You can post ur comment as answer, so that I can tick it as answer. Thanx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to have it as an answer too: if the site itself is up and running, and only the DNS record is pointing to another IP, you can easily do this locally by adding an entry in `hosts` file. The location of this file is OS dependent, but here is a comprehensive collection for them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Why is this expected to work? Shared web hosting means that the provider will run multiple sites on the same web server, thus multiple DNS records will point to the same IP address. The IP layer will make no differentiation, thus the application layer has to allow this. The http protocol defines a header named [host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host), that is the perfect solution for that. This field is always populated when the browser is trying to access the remote location by name. But beneath there is the OS name resolution mechanism that resolves the name to IP. There are multiple ways to do that on a network. DNS is only one of them. And because it is a legacy, using some sort of plain text approach is also available. This is the `hosts` file. Beware: this has an effect not only on the browser but on all name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

# Define the URL of a local file
file_url = 'http://example.com/file.txt'

# Access the file from the IP address
def access_file(192.168.130.41):
    try:
        # Download the file using the IP address and file URL
        response = requests.get(url)
        
        # If the download is successful, open the file for writing
        if response.status_code == 200:
            with open('downloaded_file.txt', 'wb') as file:
                file.write(response.content)
            print('File downloaded successfully')
        else:
            print('File download failed')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')

# Call the function and pass the IP address and file URL
access_file(192.168.130.41)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**